# Can't modify values at addresses allocated by malloc()

Tags: c, pointers, floating-point, printf

In the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    float *a; 
    printf("%x\n",&a);
    a = malloc(100*sizeof(float));
    printf("%x\n",a);
    *a=5;
    printf("%x\n",*a);
}
```

I expect to see "5" in the  final output, but all I see is zero. How can I modify those memory space?

Comment: Why are you using an unsigned hexadecimal integer specifier to print a `float`?

Comment: `%x` is a pointer, `%f` a float. `man printf`

Comment: oh god :) for some reason I thought I could print everything with %x

Comment: ... and pointer values should be printed with `%p` and not `%x`. Read about `printf`.

Comment: @Boiethios: "*%x is a pointer*" no, the `x` conversion specifier is for unsigned integers.

Comment: @alk yes I wrote too fast...

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I expect to see "5" in the final output, but all I see is zero. How
>   can I modify those memory space?

Use `"%f"` (or `"%g"` etc appropriate identifier) to print the value. (Or use explicit casting to `unsigned int` and print `sizeof(double) * CHAR_BIT` bits)

Printing a `double` argument with `"%u"` `printf` format specifier leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Related post: [Understanding implicit conversions for printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751361/understanding-implicit-conversions-for-printf/26751407#26751407)

> Can't modify values at addresses allocated by malloc()

You should be able to modify the contents on conforming implementation if `a` is not `NULL`. There is problem in presenting the data.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the working answer to your question. It seems to be about printf() format specifiers and entering float value as float, not as integer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
float *a; 
printf("%p\n",(void*)a);
a = malloc(100*sizeof(float));
printf("%p\n",(void*)a);
if(a != NULL) *a=5.0;
printf("%f\n",*a);
}
```

The terminal output then looks like this:

```
> ./a.out
0x0
0x1031009a0
5.000000
>
```

Comment: Don't print uninitialized pointer. Cast pointer to `void *` before printing.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion @Mohit Jain - I improved my reply by including it. Although "printfing" uninitialized pointers provenly works with my BSD UNIX, one always has to be extra cautious with _uninitialized pointers_ in portable code. (-: