# How printf determine the content to be printed when a char pointer is passed with different format specifiers?

Tags: c, string, printf, format-specifiers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int a = 6;
    int *pa;
    pa = &a;
    printf("%d\n",*pa); //6
    printf("%d\n",pa); //1575619476
    printf("%s\n",pa); //nothing, a empty line

    char *s="test";
    printf("%d\n",s); //183013286
    printf("%s\n",s); //test
}
```

The code is simple,
pa is a int typed pointer, we print pa, we get a memory address, we print *pa, we get its value;

But when it comes to a char typed pointer, things get interesting, it seems that printf can pick up the according type that it needs to output,

- it needs a number, the "s" will give its address since it is a
  pointer;
- it needs a string, the "s" will give the value to it.

OR does it means it is "s"'s responsible to give the proper value to printf? But it is not a object, how does the single value know some self-action?

what happened here?

Comment: It's *undefined behaviour*, not that interesting :)

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25926901/what-will-be-its-output-and-why/25926927

Comment: @P.P. Thanks, damn Clion

Answer (score 3):

In your code,

```
 printf("%d\n",pa);
 printf("%s\n",pa);
```

and

```
 printf("%d\n",s);
```

invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you're passing wrong type of arguments. Never rely on the output.

Comment: Code with bugs does strange things. Fix the bugs and the mystery goes away.

Comment: Damn, I use CLion with its Cmake 3.5, it gives me this result

Answer (score 0):

The field formatter %d means "convert the value of this variable to a decimal representation". So it always outputs a number, be it a normal value or the address carried by apointer.

The field formatter %s means "display the bytes from that address until you meet a null. So it outputs a string of characters of some length or raises a memory error if the variable is not holding an allowed address.